# Trying to write simple DSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to write a code like below:

```
MyModule::MyClass.configure do |item|
  item.var1 = 'dsads'
  item.var2 = 'dsadsa'
  item.var3 = 'fdsfdsfd'
end
```

Well, I define a module and a class within it:

```
module MyModule
 class MyClass
 end
end
```

...and what should I do further?

Comment: The question title and the question aren't similar. Could you please fix that? EDIT: Ok good, you fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do configuration, then I would recommend that you use a `Singleton` class, like this:

```
require 'singleton'
module MyModule
 class MyClass
   include Singleton
 end
end
```

Then you will need to define the `configure` method on this:

```
require 'singleton'
module MyModule
 class MyClass
   include Singleton
   def self.configure
     yield(self)
   end
 end
end
```

`yield` will evaluate the block within the context of the class, meaning that any methods called on the block object will be called on the class object.

Then for each method you call inside the `configure` block, you will need a corresponding method definition inside the class. You can do this by defining the methods manually:

```
 class MyClass
   def self.var1=(value)
     @var1 = value
   end

   def self.var1
     @var1
   end 
 end
```

Or, you can use `attr_accessor`:

```
 class MyClass
   class << self
     attr_accessor :var1
   end
 end
```

To get the values back out, just do this:

```
 MyMoudle::MyClass.var1
```

If you don't want to use a singleton, then change the class represented `MyClass` to be a module instead.

Comment: How do I do that without using Singleton?

Comment: I guess you forgot something in `def self.configure
     yield self
   end`. That's yield self.

Comment: Without using singleton is at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should write class method that takes block as an argument an yields it with newly created instance of item. Something like this

```
class MyClass
  def self.configure
    if block_given?
      item = ItemClass.new
      yield(item)
    end
  end
end
```